# Magento 2 - How To Display Cross Sell Products On Product Details Page (PDP)?

Tags: magento2, product, sales

I need to show cross sell products on pdp (Product Detail Page ) page , like currently related products shows , hows it possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please follow below instruction to display cross sell products on product page :

Create module registration file :

app/code/Test/Crosssell/registration.php

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Test_Crosssell',
    __DIR__
);
```

app/code/Test/Crosssell/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Test_Crosssell" setup_version="1.0.0" schema_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

app/code/Test/Crosssell/Block/Crosssell.php

```
<?php

namespace Test\Crosssell\Block;

class Crosssell extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {

    protected $_registry;

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context, \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry, array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_registry = $registry;

        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getCurrentProduct() {
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
    }

    public function getItems() {
        $items = $this->getData('items');
        if ($items === null) {
            $product = $this->getCurrentProduct();
            $items = $product->getCrossSellProducts();
            $this->setData('items', $items);
        }
        return $items;
    }

    public function getItemCount() {
        return count($this->getItems());
    }

}
```

app/code/Test/Crosssell/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.options.wrapper">
            <block class="Test\Crosssell\Block\Crosssell" name="test.crosssell" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml" after="-">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">crosssell</argument>
                </arguments>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="crosssell.product.addto" as="addto">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                           name="crosssell.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                           template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
        <move element="test.crosssell" destination="content" after="product.info.media"/>   
    </body>
</page>
```

After creating above module please run below command :

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Now on product page you can see crosssell products. :)

Comment: Do you know why I get HTTP ERROR 500 when I try this?

Comment: It works at my end.

Comment: I found the issue. I forgot to update my namespace in Crosssell.php. Thanks.

Comment: For me i get an error "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function toHtml() on null " Any idea where i have gone wrong here?

Comment: If i remove the image out of items.phtml where the tohtml function is my page loads with a list of the amount of products just no product data like names ect. Not sure what i have missed out here.

Comment: I think there may be an issue with this in 2.1.X i have this working again however here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/181497/crosssell-products-on-product-page-with-magento-2

Answer (score 2):

It will be better to use default logic...

app/design/frontend/vendor_name/theme_name/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <referenceContainer name="content.aside">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Crosssell" name="catalog.product.crosssell" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">crosssell</argument>
                    </arguments>
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="crosssell.product.addto" as="addto">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                           name="crosssell.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                           template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
                    </block>
                </block>
            </referenceContainer>
        </body>
    </page>
```

Comment: It's working only when you add product to basket. So there no benefit.