# Changing Title of Crossell's and Gaps Products Block

Tags: magento2, product-images, product-view, cross-sells, product-view-page

I implemented the extension development from [Crosssell Products on Product Page with Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/181497/crosssell-products-on-product-page-with-magento-2) on Magento 2.2.0. It is currently running, but there are several modifications needed.

1. The gap between the previous block content and next content (either margin or padding)
2. The title said "More Choices" need to change with "You May Also Like?"

I attached this screenshot here:

[image: Cross Sell Product on Product Detail Page]

I'm using Unero Theme for additional information (I put the XML block in the Theme frontend of Magento Catalog -> catalog_product_view.xml ) and I still in an early stage of understanding Magento codes and devs. Thanks before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the title of More Choices You have to override the

> /vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/items.phtml

to in your theme

> /app/design/frontend/[Theme_Vendor]/[Theme]/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/items.phtml

In this file replace find the below line of code

```
$title = __('More Choices:');
```

And replace it with

```
$title = __('You May Also Like?');
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: So, I have to copy the items.phtml in Magento's core module into the theme's one (so, Magento's code remain intact ?) ? Where to change the translation's part if change is already implemented. Thank you very much for your answer @Kishor

Comment: For the translation, you have to create the csv file on app/design/[Theme_Vendor]/[Theme]/i18n/en_US.csv and add content like "More Choices:","More Choices:"